# SSRS 2008 R2 trying to group dates/get a range of dates on the x axis

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, linechart

So I'm trying to create a report from my database that shows people joining over time. The y axis is # of people and the x axis is the date. I am trying to have each major tick on the x axis be a different quarter of the year. My problem is that when I try to group by DATEPART(year,date) then DATEPART(month,date) it does nothing. Every tick on the x axis is another individual day, so I end up with like hundreds of individual days and my line never really goes above one person because they all join on different days....(Also there is a time added to the field so its yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00. So the time is always 0, don't know if that makes a difference or not) I've tried setting the min and max date with the interval to 3 and interval type to months but that just makes it show ever 3rd month and I want to be able to show all of the people from those three months on the same major tick. I'm not sure if it could also be changed through my sql statement that I write to assign to the categories when I'm first creating the chart... I hope I've made my problem clear and if anyone has any advice or ideas I'd love to hear them! Thanks in advance! Ohh yea and a side note, if anyone knows how to display 2 lines(males vs females) that would be great! I have that but them I'm stuck with a stupid "series" line that I can't get ride of. Anyways the first question is way more important :)

Comment: this is my sql statement so far:    SELECT DATENAME(mm, Q02) AS Month, DATENAME(yyyy, Q02) AS Year, count(ID) AS Total, Q06 AS Gender
FROM F01
GROUP BY DATEPART(month, Q02), DATENAME(yyyy, Q02), DATENAME(mm, Q02)
ORDER BY Year, DATEPART(month, Q02) My graph still doesn't go above one because the ID's are unique because they are on individual days

Comment: How does this query work?  Q06 is in the select clause but not in the group by clause.

Comment: ahh damn I forgot to put it in. It goes GROUP BY Q06, DATEPART(month,Q02), etc. Cause I want to group by gender first then the dates